# Is there a way to change url to the next url in python

Tags: python, url

I am making a loop in python

```
url1 = 
url2 = 
url3 =
currenturl = 
status = False
while not status:

   ....
   ...
   if .... :
   currenturl = url(1+1) (I want to change my currenturl to the next one)

   status = True
```

is there a way to do this?

Comment: Just use List..

Comment: Do what the previous commenter said and use a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  Please work through tutorials on lists and loops.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a list for this purpose. You can use list like this:

```
url = ['abc.com', 'xyz.com', 'pqr.com']
while not status:
    if ...:
        currenturl = url[i]
        i+=1
        status = False
```

However if you want to stick to this variable names you can use globals(). Initialize a variable `i` and then increment it to use next urls.

```
url1 = 
url2 = 
url3 =
currenturl = 
status = False
i=1
while not status:

   ....
   ...
   if .... :
   i+=1
   currenturl = globals()["url" + str(i)]

   status = True
```